# In jQuery, how do you add markup above your selected DOM element?

Tags: jquery

If i have:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

How do I select the test div and then add `<div id="pre-test">` before the test div so it looks like this:

```
<div id="pre-test"><div id="test"></div>
```

Thanks guys

Comment: You are missing a `</div>` closing tag so it's not fully clear whether `#pre-test` is a sibling or an ancestor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("<div id='pre-test'/>").insertBefore("#test");`

[insertBefore documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)

Alternatively, you can use the `.before(...)` method like so:

`$("#test").before("<div id='pre-test'/>");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use insertBefore (http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)

```
$('<div id="pre-test">').insertBefore($('#test'));
```

Comment: @strelokstrelok beat me to it :)
Our solutions look different but work similar (afaik).

Do check out the jQuery documentation, it's pretty good. And you can use Google to search in it.

    site:http://api.jquery.com insert